# Can't login after my site was moved to a new server

Tags: urls, server

I'm working on a site which is not attached to a domain name yet, so I access to it through an ugly URL like old_server.something.myprovider.co.uk/.../.../

My provider moved me to a new server so I now have to type : new_server.something.myprovider.co.uk/.../.../

Problem is, when trying to access wp-admin, WordPress performs some sort of redirection to the old address and of course it doesn't work anymore. So I can't access the login page.

Is there a way to change the server URL in WordPress without accessing the dashboard ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes cou can change it by accessing the database of your wordpress. It's located in the `wp_options` table of your wp' database. You'll have to change two values; the **`siteurl`** (line 1) and the **`home`** (line 37).

You can access it through the admin panel of your host and/or sometimes directly by typing in your browser the `DB_HOST` value you entered for the installation of the blog, now written in your `wp_config.php` file at the root of your site. Then just use the login and password also written in this file.

This should do it.

EDIT: i recommend the use of this [kind of plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/) to clean completely the database to change all your http://yourolddomain.com/whatever/ to http://yournewdomain.com/whatever/.

Answer (score 1):

One of the quick things you can do is to edit wp_config.php. You'll want to do two things:

1. change the database connection information if you need to (as @kevin mentions)
2. add define('RELOCATE', true); to the very last bit of the file just above the line that says "stop editing"

Now, save wp_config.php and then go directly to the wp-login.php on your new url:
http://new_server.something/myprovider.co.uk/.../.../wp-login.php

Login, and then immediately go to Settings > General and make sure you synchronize the URL in home and site url fields (RELOCATE only does the one, not the other). Save. Test.

Then, go back into wp_config.php and remove the RELOCATE definition you added in step 2.

Hope this works for you!

note: you'll run into additional difficulties if your database tables prefix has changed, but that doesn't appear to be the case according to what you described.

T